# How to fake color "surface" of fake sphere made with html and css

Tags: css, css-animations

I am trying to create a sphere from scratch in only html and css

I am able to create multiple divs, apply a border radius to them, and then rotate them so they give the illusion of a sphere, but the issue is at the moment it is only a "mesh" created with the borders of the divs. how would i go about coloring in between the spaces?

here is what ive got so far https://codepen.io/jaypitti/pen/zYBMdeG

html

```
    <div class="Sphere">
        <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
        <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
        <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
        <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
        <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
        <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
    </div>
```

css

```
.Sphere {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0.0);
  width: 25rem;
  height: 25rem;
}

.SphereMesh {
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(1,75,236,0.1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.SphereMesh:nth-child(1) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(30deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  animation: 5s rotateChild1 linear infinite;
}

.SphereMesh:nth-child(2) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(60deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  animation: 5s rotateChild2 linear infinite;
}

.SphereMesh:nth-child(3) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  animation: 5s rotateChild3 linear infinite;
}

.SphereMesh:nth-child(4) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(120deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  animation: 5s rotateChild4 linear infinite;
}

.SphereMesh:nth-child(5) {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(150deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  animation: 5s rotateChild5 linear infinite;
}

.SphereMesh:nth-child(6) {
  transform: rotateX(deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  animation: 5s rotateChild6 linear infinite;
}

@keyframes rotateChild1 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(60deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid blue; border-left: 5px solid green;}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(390deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid green; border-left: 5px solid blue;}
}

@keyframes rotateChild2 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(90deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid blue; border-left: 5px solid green;}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(420deg)rotateZ(0deg) ; border-right: 5px solid green; border-left: 5px solid blue;}
}

@keyframes rotateChild3 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(120deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid blue; border-left: 5px solid green;}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(450deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid green; border-left: 5px solid blue;}
}

@keyframes rotateChild4 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(150deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid blue; border-left: 5px solid green;}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(480deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid green; border-left: 5px solid blue;}
}

@keyframes rotateChild5 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(180deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid blue; border-left: 5px solid green;}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(510deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid green; border-left: 5px solid blue;}
}

@keyframes rotateChild6 {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(210deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid blue; border-left: 5px solid green;}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(540deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid green; border-left: 5px solid blue;}
}
```

there is probably a lot better and cleaner way to accomplish what I am doing above so if you have any critiques (as im sure you will) please help me improve it!

is this even possible with the way im trying to do it? im not very good at css and im trying to learn so if there are any similar articles or resources you can provide that explain in detail a process the same or similar to what im trying to accomplish please link it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The 'gaps' in the sphere are caused by the divs representing each grid line having borders which are outside the actual div from the point of view of the browser positioning the elements.

If we use a border-box we can get the browser to put margins/padding/border within the basic element so it doesn't shift its position.

We can also tidy up the code quite a bit by recognising that each element is doing the same animation, just at slightly different times.

Here is a version tidied up as far as I could. I should have liked to use a CSS variable for the spin time and then a calc for each animation-delay but, although I found these shown as examples, it was not seen as a valid value (at least by Edge on Windows 10). I have therefore cheated to make the maths easy for this test and set the rotation time to 6 seconds and therefore each mesh div n to have an animation-delay of -(n-1) seconds. Of course this can be set to deal with whatever you really want the spin time to be. It is just unfortunate that it seems we have to do that by hand for each child.

```css
.Sphere {
  position: absolute;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.0);
  width: 25rem;
  height: 25rem;
  background: radial-gradient(circle at 50% 120%, #81e8f6, #76deef 10%, #055194 80%, #062745 100%);
}


  
.SphereMesh {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  border-radius: 50%;
  position: absolute;
  border: 5px solid black;
  background-color: rgba(1,75,236,0.1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.SphereMesh {
  transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(30deg) rotateZ(0deg);
  animation: 6s rotateChild linear infinite;
}


.SphereMesh:nth-child(1) {
  animation-delay: 0s;
}

.SphereMesh:nth-child(2) {
  animation-delay: -1s;
}

.SphereMesh:nth-child(3) {
  animation-delay: -2s;
}

.SphereMesh:nth-child(4) {
  animation-delay: -3s;
}

.SphereMesh:nth-child(5) {
  animation-delay: -4s;
}

.SphereMesh:nth-child(6) {
  animation-delay: -5s;
}

@keyframes rotateChild {
  0% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(60deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid blue; border-left: 5px solid green;}
  100% { -webkit-transform: rotateX(0deg) rotateY(390deg) rotateZ(0deg); border-right: 5px solid green; border-left: 5px solid blue;}
}
```

```html
        <div class="Sphere">
            <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
            <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
            <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
            <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
            <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
            <div class="SphereMesh"></div>
        </div>
```